# Apache POI 3.16 Excel Download Open issue

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

There is an error when I download and open the Excel file. I haven't worked this out for three days. I want you to help me.

poi 3.16
poi-ooxml 3.16
poi-ooxml-schemas 3.16
poi-scratchpad 3.16

**1. Download and open file normally**

```java
        Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
        Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("sheet1");
        Row row = null;
        Cell cell = null;
        int rowNum = 0;

        row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
        cell = row.createCell(0);
        cell.setCellValue("no");

        for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
            row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
            cell = row.createCell(0);
            cell.setCellValue(i);
        }

        response.setContentType("ms-vnd/excel");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=example.xls");

        // Excel File Output
        wb.write(response.getOutputStream());
        wb.close();
```

**2. Download and don't open the file**

```java
        Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
        Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("sheet1");
        Row row = null;
        Cell cell = null;
        int rowNum = 0;

        row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
        cell = row.createCell(0);
        cell.setCellValue("no");

        for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
            row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
            cell = row.createCell(0);
            cell.setCellValue(i);
        }

        response.setContentType("ms-vnd/excel");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=example.xlsx");

        // Excel File Output
        wb.write(response.getOutputStream());
        wb.close();
```

[errorImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9QuI.png)

And I've also written this on "xlsx" -> application/vnd.openxmlformats-offered document.spreadsheetml.sheet

It doesn't open the same way.

Is there a bug in 3.16?

It sounds a little weird, but I tried one more thing.

**3. Open but abnormally open**

```java
OutputStream out = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream bout = null;
        
        try {
            bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            wb.write(bout);
            
            setHeader(request, response, fileName);
            response.setContentLength(bout.size());
            
            autoSizeColumns(wb);
            
            out = response.getOutputStream();

            wb.write(out);
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            
            try { 
                if (out != null) bout.close();
                if (out != null) out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { 
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            }
        }
```

Workbooks are created elsewhere.

If I write it like this, there will be an error as below.

[errorImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odluO.png)

When I press Yes, the file opens and the contents are visible, but the style is broken.

Comment: why use a 5.5 year old version of POI - please try POI 5.2.2

Comment: _Is there a bug in 3.16?_  Yes; they are summarized [here](https://poi.apache.org/devel/history/changes-3x.html) and [here](https://poi.apache.org/changes.html). Why _not_ upgrade?

Comment: Some of the functions of other projects need to be imported, but the POI versions are different. If I upload the version, there are too many parts that I have to work on.